# R pie chart with percentages

Tags: r, pie-chart

I have this df

```r
species<-c("Platanus acerifolia Willd.","Platanus acerifolia Willd.","Platanus occidentalis L.",
           "Morus alba L.","Platanus occidentalis L.","Celtis australis L.")
kategorija<-c(3,2,1,2,3,3)

df<-data.frame(species,kategorija)
```

and I need to make a pie chart from the frequencies of the categories labelled with their percentages.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
pie(table(df$kategorija), labels = paste(round(prop.table(table(df$kategorija))*100), "%", sep = ""), col=rainbow(nrow(df)))
legend('topright', legend = paste('category', table(df$kategorija)), fill=rainbow(nrow(df)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also make the pie plot using `dplyr` and `ggplot`. It requires a little more of coding, but the result might be more satisfactory.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

#Use dplyr to get percentages per kategorija
df_plot<-df %>% 
  count(kategorija) %>% 
  mutate(percent = round((100 * n / sum(n)),2))

#Create the bar plot
p2 <- ggplot(df_plot, aes(x = "", y = percent, fill = factor(kategorija)))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity") +
  #Transform the bar plot to pie plot
  coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
  #Add labels to each part of the pie and add some theme adjustments
  geom_text(aes(y = cumsum(rev(percent)) - rev(percent)/2, 
                       label = paste(rev(percent),"%")), size=4) +
  # Add label for legend
  labs(fill = "Kategorija")+
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

This code created the following plot:
[image: Pie plot]

Comment: Thanks, but I have a problem, R doesn't give me plot, codes are okay and R accept them, but doesn't show me plot :(

Comment: After running the code I posted, did you run just `p2` in a new line? That should show the plot.

Comment: I made a little change and I made a mistake, so cuz of that It won't run, but now its work. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easy way to do this using `ggstatsplot`:

```r
library(ggstatsplot)

species <- c(
  "Platanus acerifolia Willd.", "Platanus acerifolia Willd.", "Platanus occidentalis L.",
  "Morus alba L.", "Platanus occidentalis L.", "Celtis australis L."
)

kategorija <- c(3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3)

df <- data.frame(species, kategorija)

ggpiestats(df, species, counts = kategorija, results.subtitle = FALSE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>